# Arithmetic of uncountable ordinal

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Assume $\alpha$ is an ordinal such that $\alpha \geq \omega_1$.  Is it true then that $\alpha = \omega + \alpha$ with respect to ordinal arithmetic?

Comment: Yes, it is true! It is not true that $\alpha=\alpha+\omega$ though.

Comment: Right, because ordinal addition is not commutative.  Okay thanks!

Comment: As answered below, $\omega+\alpha=\alpha$ iff $\alpha=\omega^2$. Try to prove something more general: $\alpha=\omega^\beta$ for some $\beta$ iff $\gamma+\alpha=\alpha$ for all $\gamma<\alpha$.

Comment: You mean iff $\alpha \geq \omega^2$.

Comment: @gorzardfu Yes, of course. Sorry about the typo.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, $\alpha=\omega+\alpha\iff\alpha\ge\omega^2.$

Suppose $\alpha=\omega+\alpha.$ Then, by induction, $\alpha=\omega\cdot n+\alpha\ge\omega\cdot n$ for every $n\lt\omega,$ whence $\alpha\ge\omega^2.$

Suppose $\alpha\ge\omega^2.$ Then $\alpha=\omega^2+\xi$ for some ordinal $\xi.$ Since$$\omega+\omega^2=\omega\cdot1+\omega\cdot\omega=\omega(1+\omega)=\omega\cdot\omega=\omega^2,$$
it follows that 
$$\omega+\alpha=\omega+\omega^2+\xi=\omega^2+\xi=\alpha.$$

Comment: I think you stated the first part of the statement and it's proof incorrectly.  Do you mean α = ω + α iff ... ? And in the proof, did you mean to suppose that same thing?

Comment: @gorzardfu Thanks for the correction.